# A particular diff

Tags: rebol, red

I have 2 files: **list-folder1.txt** and **list-folder2.txt**. These files are derived from the `ls -1R` command run on linux in their respective folders (similar folders consisting of thousands of files and some subdirectories). I would like a **difference.txt** file with the list of files present in **list-folder2.txt** but not present in **list-folder1.txt** also indicating the folder. (Example: `ls -1R examples > list-folder-old.txt` is:

```
examples:
c
lua

examples/c:
Makefile
env.c
helloworld.c

examples/lua:
fizzbuzz.lua
```

`ls -1R examples > list-folder.txt` is:

```
examples:
c
lua
file1.txt

examples/c:
Makefile
env.c
file2.txt
helloworld.c

examples/lua:
file3.txt
fizzbuzz.lua
```

difference.txt shuold be:

```
examples:
file1.txt

examples/c:
file2.txt

examples/lua:
file3.txt
```

Is there an easy way in Reboland to solve this problem? Is it better to use read with parse or read/lines?

Answer (score 1):

Given your example file, you can try using `exclude` to subtract the second set of lines from the first one. E.g.:

```
write/lines %difference.txt exclude read/lines %list-folder2.txt read/lines %list-folder1.txt
```

That should work for both Red and Rebol. In case of Red, if you want to use it from a batch script, I recommend downloading the "CLI Red" version from the [download](https://www.red-lang.org/p/download.html) page.

> Is it better to use read with parse or read/lines?

If the need is just to split the file into lines that can be directly processed, go with `read/lines`. If anything more than that is needed, then go with `read` then `parse`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Indeed your script shows the missing files but I lose the information of the folder where they are. I have improved the example.